# Formatting x-axis with histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, drawing, histogram

I want x- axis from 1 to 20 and y-axis from 1 to 6.
My data:

```
structure(list(HEI.ID = structure(c(12L, 9L, 14L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 
7L, 5L, 11L, 3L, 10L, 18L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 15L, 13L, 17L, 4L, 16L
), .Label = c("BF", "CC", "DC", "ER", "IM", "MC", "ME      ", 
"MM", "MO", "OC", "OM", "OP", "SB", "SD", "SH", "SL", "SN", "TH", 
"UN", "WS"), class = "factor"), X2007 = c(18L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 
12L, 6L, 17L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 16L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 
3L, 19L), X2008 = c(20L, 9L, 16L, 18L, 8L, 17L, 15L, 6L, 3L, 
14L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 11L, 7L, 4L, 10L), X2009 = c(20L, 
13L, 17L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 19L, 12L, 2L, 11L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 
18L, 5L, 15L, 9L, 14L), X2010 = c(20L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 7L, 15L, 
19L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 18L, 1L, 5L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 17L), 
    X2011 = c(20L, 2L, 16L, 14L, 6L, 10L, 17L, 8L, 3L, 15L, 19L, 
    1L, 4L, 18L, 13L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 4L, 7L), X2012 = c(20L, 12L, 
    19L, 13L, 8L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 17L, 2L, 7L, 18L, 5L, 
    16L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L)), .Names = c("HEI.ID", "X2007", "X2008", 
"X2009", "X2010", "X2011", "X2012"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I use the following commands to draw histograms:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,4))
for(i in  1:20){
  print(i)
  hist(as.numeric(HEIrank11[i,-1]),nclass=12,,main='students/faculty',
       xlab = STOF[i,1],cex.lab=1, cex.axis=1, cex.main=1, cex.sub=1)
 }
```

But after using above commands, I get different number in x- axis and y-axis.

Comment: Cna you make your question reproducible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: See the link I provided. It has all the information you need on how to convey your data to us with minimal hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `xlim` and `ylim` parameters in the `hist` function and control the axes using
`axis`:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,4))
for(i in  1:12){
  print(i)  
  hist(as.numeric(HEIrank11[i,-1]),nclass=12,,main='students/faculty',
       xlim=c(0, 21), ylim=c(0,6), xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  axis(1, at=c(0, 10, 20))
  axis(2, at=0:6)  
}
```

Do you really want your y-axis to go from 1 to 6? This will cut off parts of the bars.
Also, you iterate over all 20 rows for a grid with 12 plots. The code above gives the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your plot would looks like. It's not clear from your question and data provided.

I've tried to plot it. Please comment if you think it's the way to go.

Considering `dt` is your data.frame

```
library(reshape)
dt <- melt(dt)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=HEI.ID, y = value, fill = variable), data = dt) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image: histogram]

or

```
ggplot(aes(x=HEI.ID, y = value, fill = variable), data = dt1) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  facet_grid(variable ~.)
```

[image]